# How to fix "WebConnect: Starting server failed. Try to remove stale socket." when attempting to debug in Kdevelop?

Tags: c++, kdevelop

I downloaded the code for KMyMoney in Git. 
 git clone https://github.com/KDE/kmymoney.git

I installed Kdevelop in Fedora 30. I installed all the dependencies.

I opened Kdevelop and imported my project.

When I try to debug, I get this error:

WebConnect: Starting server failed. Try to remove stale socket.
WebConnect: Running in server mode
*** Program received signal SIGSEGV (Segmentation fault) ***

I did change the debugger to GDB. However, it still fails.

I cannot get Kdevelop to debug KMyMoney. I need help trying to get the debugger to connect. No idea how to do it.

thanks,

JV

Answer (score 0):

When starting the Debug session, try going to the GDB tool-view.

It should be in the bottom panel of KDevelop when the debug session starts. When inside that tool-view right-click and choose 'show internal commands'.

That will give you all the commands KDevelop is issuing to the gdb debugger and should help you find out what the root cause of your problem is.